# django tutorial, not loading my static files properly

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

It's my fault I'm following different tutorials, but the first one worked well enough and figured I'd follow a more detailed one. Anyway, the first one had me move the templates folder outside the blog app and move it to the route, so I have the following on the settings:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

problem with that tutorial, it did not include any static setups for css and whatever static files I would need. That said, I'm following another tutorial that has me placed the css like so

```
|- blog
|---static
|-----blog
|-------main.css
|- django_app
|---all the settings found here
|- templates
|---blog
|-----all my templates are here
```

and had this on the base.html of the templates to

```
<style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'blog/main.css' %}"></style>
```

but my template does not find it. I was able to trace my css through the following url

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/blog/main.css
```

Idk what the best practice is with django and it's folder structure but any advice is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You should set `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL` in `settings.py`. follow this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/)

Comment: correct me if im wrong but the static_root only used for when deployment correct? im still on my local, and the static_url is already there and i also placed the STATICFILES_DIRS mentioned on the link. also added these on the blog.urls "+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)" , not sure what else I'm missing

Comment: could you `cd` into your `project directory` and run `tree`  and show us the output of your project structure? The one you give is hard to understand & hard to help you

Answer (score -1):

This is purely my suggestion there might be better ways.

### settings.py

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

### Folder Structure

```
├───django_app
└───blog
    ├───static
    │   ├───css    // folder for css files
    │   ├───img    // folder for image files
    │   └───js     // folder for javascript files
    └───templates
        └───blog   // html files for blog app
```

**Html page**

```py
....
....
 {% load static %}
....
....
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/css/sample.css' %}">
....
....
```